# 1px solid image efficiency

Tags: html, image, pixel

Would it be more efficient to make a 5x5 solid color image, or would it be more efficient to stretch a 1x1 pixel solid color image to fit the 5x5 image criteria?

```
<img src="red.png" width="5px" height="5px" />
```

Comment: If you just need it to be a solid colour then I'd say using a div or similar with an explicit `background-colour` would be better than an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it'd be more efficient to render a div with a background color

```
<div style="background:red; width:5px; height:5px"></div>
```